# How to retrieve file from Google appFolder in my android app

Tags: android

```
final Task<DriveFolder> appFolderTask = getDriveResourceClient().getAppFolder();
final Task<DriveContents> createContentsTask = getDriveResourceClient().createContents();
Tasks.whenAll(appFolderTask, createContentsTask)
        .continueWithTask(new Continuation<Void, Task<DriveFile>>() {
            @Override
            public Task<DriveFile> then(@NonNull Task<Void> task) throws Exception {
                DriveFolder parent = appFolderTask.getResult();
                DriveContents contents = createContentsTask.getResult();
                OutputStream outputStream = contents.getOutputStream();
                try (Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream)) {
                    writer.write(data);
                }

                MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                        .setTitle("Demo`enter code here`")
                        .setMimeType("text/plain")
                        .setStarred(true)
                        .build();

                return getDriveResourceClient().createFile(parent, changeSet, contents);
            }
        })
        .addOnSuccessListener(this,
                new OnSuccessListener<DriveFile>() {
                    @SuppressLint("StringFormatInvalid")
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(DriveFile driveFile) {
                        showMessage(getString(R.string.file_created,
                                driveFile.getDriveId().encodeToString()));
                        //finish();
                    }
                })
        .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Unable to create file", e);
                showMessage(getString(R.string.file_create_error));
                //finish();
            }
        });
```

I have successfully uploaded the file into app folder but didn't get any resource for retrieve from Drive's app folder.

How it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

**I have got my answer by just calling getAppFolder method from driveResourceClient instance**

```
 final Task<DriveFolder> appfolder = getDriveResourceClient().getAppFolder();
    appfolder.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DriveFolder>() {
      @Override
      public void onSuccess(DriveFolder driveFolder) {
        listFilesInFolder(driveFolder);
      }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
      @Override
      public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

      }
    });

private void listFilesInFolder(final DriveFolder folder) {
    Query query = new Query.Builder()
            .addFilter(Filters.eq(SearchableField.TITLE, "File.txt"))
            .build();
    // [START query_children]
    //Task<MetadataBuffer> queryTask = getDriveResourceClient().queryChildren(folder, query);
    Task<MetadataBuffer> queryTask = getDriveResourceClient().listChildren(folder);
    // END query_children]
    queryTask
            .addOnSuccessListener(this,
                    new OnSuccessListener<MetadataBuffer>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(MetadataBuffer metadataBuffer) {

                          for (int i=0; i<metadataBuffer.getCount(); i++){
                            Metadata mb = metadataBuffer.get(0);
                            Log.e("File name", mb.getOriginalFilename());
                          }
                            if (metadataBuffer.getCount() > 0) {
                                Metadata mb = metadataBuffer.get(0);

                            retrieveContents(mb.getDriveId().asDriveFile());


                            } else {

                              listFilesInFolder(folder);


                              showMessage("There are no File Found.");

                            }

                        }
                    })
            .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error retrieving files", e);
                    showMessage(getString(R.string.query_failed));
                    finish();
                }
            });

}
```

Comment: Hey bro, can you share your "retrieveContents" method, i want to take the file and put it inside some folder in the device?

Comment: You can get your content from my above code snippet.Thanks.

Comment: Maybe I am not understand something, So I am understand that you get the AppFolder and take some file from inside?
Next, you use Method "retrieveContents" to copy the content of the file from AppFolder inside the file on the device Am I right?
So I use your snippet but I am stuck on copy the content of AppFolder File inside the file on device... Can you help me pleaseeee?